# Is this comparison structure correct?

Tags: sentence-structure

In my native language it makes sense when I say a sentence like that:

> Arabic uses the past continuous tense different than English.

Is it  okay to say a sentence like that in English? I'm talking about the comparison in this sentence which are the words (different & than).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to describe an action verb ("uses"), you need to use an adverb, which in this case would be "differently".

> Arabic uses the past continuous tense differently than English [does].

Or, you could rephrase it:

> Arabic uses the past continuous tense in a different way than English.

Comment: So I was confusing between comparing nouns and verbs. Thank you for clarifying it to me :) the word [does] is written like that because it's a must, not optional, right?

Comment: No, it's more correct, but often omitted.